# SQL Find Records Where Date is Not Unique

Tags: t-sql

I have a table in which a file is imported daily and, unfortunately, it was created without a constraint so I have to find issues where the same records may have been imported two days in a row.

So, I want to write a query that will tell me when records with a particular "header date" were imported more than once (the header date should be unique each day).  The field I'm using for import date is a datetime "dataDate" field.  My header date field is called "headerDate" and is a datetime field as well, and my table is tblCases.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the dates with more than one row:

```
SELECT headerDate
FROM tblCases
GROUP BY headerDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Of course this is extendable to give you the rows that are duplicated in the table for whatever columns you specify:

```
SELECT headerDate, col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM tblCases
GROUP BY headerDate, col1, col2, col3, ...
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the detail on the dataDate then

```
select * 
FROM tblCases
where headerDate in 
(
    SELECT headerDate
    FROM tblCases
    GROUP BY headerDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
order by headerDate, dataDate
```